# Merge different tables based on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different data frames with these columns:

**google_df:**
google_name, placeId, google_address, google_website, google_telephone

The second data frame with these columns:

**yelp_df:**
yelp_name, yelpId, yelp_address, yelp_rating

I would like to have just one data frame, based on the columns google_name and yelp_name.
I tried with this code

```
final_df = pd.merge(google_df, yelp_df, left_on='google_name', right_on='yelp_name')
```

But the output is not what I am expecting

If the google_name and the yelp_name is the same, I would like to have just one row for this restaurant, instead of this, I am having a dataframe with repeated names of restaurants

**Output**
[image: final_data frame]

**Output expected**
Base on the image above, I want to have data frame but just one row for Five Guys, not 4 (unique row for each restaurant)

Comment: could you include a sample so that we could reproduce your issue?

Comment: There is no simple answer to your question, you probably cannot just merge on the name as this will merge different restaurants with the same name. You need to find a unique identifier common to both dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

You can adding `drop_duplicates`

```
final_df = pd.merge(google_df.drop_duplicates('google_name'),
                    yelp_df.drop_duplicates('yelp_name'), 
                    left_on='google_name', 
                    right_on='yelp_name')
```